# Idiom in magrittr for x <- x %>%

Tags: r, magrittr

With magrittr (or dplyr), I find myself using the following pattern quite often:

```
x <- x %>%
     fun %>%
     fun
```

Is there a commonly used shortcut or idiom for that? by which I mean, an operand, e.g. %^>%, with which one could write:

```
x %^>% fun ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want %<>%. You have to explicitly load magrittr though, at least I do. Check out [the reference manual on cran](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf) (page 7).